# Using Loop Function during Importing data by Data steps in SAS

Tags: sas

“Client_ID_12_months_bill.txt” contains the 12 months credit card bill against each client_id in single Import the data into SAS such that bill for each month is recorded as a separate observation and month number is also specific (Bonus question – Month name instead of month number)

In this Ques, i have Imported the data successfully.But the problem Which I am facing is that,i am not getting the value in Variable-'Balance' (instead of getting correct output i am getting only 1 in each and every observation of Variable-Balance).

## Sample Data

108263 $946.00 $903.00 $804.00 $674.00 $663.00 $195.00 $922.00 $595.00 $157.00 $415.00 $868.00 $750.00

103681 $135.00 $573.00 $642.00 $208.00 $922.00 $592.00 $425.00 $658.00 $131.00 $648.00 $750.00 $515.00

116865 $624.00 $679.00 $402.00 $636.00 $358.00 $560.00 $884.00 $514.00 $565.00 $278.00 $117.00 $852.00

102998 $747.00 $505.00 $549.00 $942.00 $884.00 $991.00 $480.00 $326.00 $447.00 $617.00 $721.00 $874.00

115569 $254.00 $792.00 $420.00 $642.00 $851.00 $258.00 $872.00 $828.00 $658.00 $260.00 $499.00 $575.00

```
   data Client_Bill (keep=client_ID balance month_num month_name i );
   infile '/folders/myfolders/SAS Assignment/Assignment 8 files 
   Part-2/Client_ID_12_months_bill.txt' truncover;
   informat month1-month12 Dollar6.2;
   input client_ID $ month1-month12;
   array months(*) month1-month12;
   do i=1 to dim(months);
   if not missing(months(i)) then do;
   balance=month(i);
   month_num=i;
   month_name=put(mdy(i,1,2017),monname.);
   output;
   end;
   end;
   run;
```

Comment: There are two other approaches to solve this problem that may be more helpful, one is proc transpose which is dynamic and the second is to read the data directly into different rows and add the month/dates afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, balance is defined as the value returned from the function `month` (note the singular form), not an element of the array months (plural form).

The `month`functions returns the number of a month, given a date. i is interpreted as a date, ie the number of days after 01JAN1960. You are giving it the values 1-12, which are all in January 1960. Thus, it returns month number 1 for all of them.

Comment: Hii Sir, please Advice me to What Corrections should i make in my Codes.

Comment: balance=month(i); should be balance=months{i};